# Can't connect Google Calendar to Fullcalendar in React/Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to use Google Calendar as a source in a Fullcalendar component in a Next.js project. The component works correctly, sourcing events is the problem.

I have been following the official tutorial (which is outdated), using an API key I generated and just the generic Google holidays calendar.
[Tutorial link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar)
This is giving me **ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined** error.

```
<Calendar
   plugins={[dayGridPlugin, listPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin]}
   initialView="listMonth"
   googleCalendarApiKey="API_KEY"
   eventSources="en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"
/>
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: eventSources is supposed to be an array, not a plain string. Check the fullCalendar docs at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

Comment: Thanks for your input! Getting a different error now:

If I set an events array within the component like so, the events do not display, but everything loads:

`events={[{googleCalendarId: "CALENDAR_ID",},]}`

Then if I change the array to 'eventSources' with the same content, and don't reload the page - the events show up. 

When I reload the page, I am still getting an XMLHttpRequest is not defined reference error.

Does this mean the events are loading at the wrong time/take too long?

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar's Calendar component indeed does take in an array for its eventSources parameter. To do this I have passed in an array variable which I have declared above using:

```
let INITIAL_EVENTS = [
        {
            googleCalendarId:'calendarID@group.calendar.google.com',
            className:'event'
        }
    ]
```

and then passed this into eventSources with

```
eventSources={INITIAL_EVENTS}
```

As a closing remark, I would use dotenv to manage your Google API key.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the googleCalendarId prop. Please adapt this to your use case:

```
   <FullCalendar
      plugins={[dayGridPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin]}
      initialView='dayGridMonth'
      weekends={true}
      firstDay={1}
      locale={esLocale}
      googleCalendarApiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CALENDAR_API_KEY}
      eventSources={[
        {
          googleCalendarId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CALENDAR_ID,
        }
      ]}
      eventContent={renderEventContent}
    />
```